# Flutter Web- playing uint8list n videoplayer

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-video-player

I am trying to play a local video file on flutter web but am getting stuck after choosing the video. According to this github post, it is possible to play a local video file by converting the uint8list of the video to a blob and then using videoController.network to play the blob: [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59387). The problem is that I am not sure how to convert to a blob properly. How do I convert a uint8list to a blob and then play that blob in the flutter video player?

Answer (score 9):

**Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob)** from **dart:html** library does the trick:

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;

// ...
    final blob = html.Blob([bytes]);
    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(url);
```

Comment: It's can't play on Safari (MacOS)!

Comment: Did you find a solution for playing on Safari MacOS?

Comment: Can anyone confirm this issue on safari and is it related to the source of the video file? Might just be an issue with the encoding or something else..